# Tcl exception: is `return -code break' the same as `break'?

Tags: exception, return, tcl

Please take a look at the following TCL code snippet:

```
proc myBreak {} {
   return -code break
}

for {set k 0} {$k<10} {incr k} {
    puts $k
    if { $k == 5} {
        # error, but this will work if using myBreak            
        return -code break
        # myBreak
    }
}
```

The error message is like:

```
invoked "break" outside of a loop
    while executing
"for {set k 0} {$k<10} {incr k} {
        puts $k
        if { $k == 5} {
                return -code break
        }
}"
    (file "test2.tcl" line 91)
```

I don't understand why it is an error, and why it is not an error if just putting `return -code break` inside a function.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `return -code break` by default returns to the caller's level and *then* raises a break exception. If you want it to raise a break in the same level, you can set the level of the return: `return -code break -level 0`.

Even in older Tcl versions, `return` works in terms of stack level, only you have less control over it. Each invocation of `return` goes back one stack level and then passes its code to the interpreter (letting it know if this is an ok return or some sort of exception).

If you execute the `for` loop from the global scope (stack level 0) and then `return -code break` from inside it, the `if` and `for` commands are tidied away and essentially `break` is executed by itself, which causes an error.

If you call `myBreak` from inside the `for` loop, the procedure executes in stack level 1. When `return -code break` is invoked, the procedure immediately terminates and execution goes back to the point where it was called. Then essentially `myBreak` passes a `break` exception to the interpreter. This is ok, since looping commands catch such exceptions.

Comment: I tried with your solution, but got error `bad option "-level": must be -code, -errorcode, or -errorinfo`. It seemed like `return` didn't have `-level` option.

Comment: @password636: then you probably have a Tcl older than 8.5. Tcl 8.4 and older are obsolete and unsupported.

Comment: yes, you are right. I tried with 8.5 and it worked. Tcl also has a better documentation for 8.5, which makes the whole thing clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanically, they're not the same. The `break` command throws a `TCL_BREAK` exception behind the scenes, which looping constructs will handle as documented (i.e., by stopping looping), whereas the `return -code break` throws a `TCL_RETURN` exception (with a detail of `TCL_BREAK`) so that the current procedure call does a `TCL_BREAK` instead of a normal exit. In short, if you do this:

```
proc example {x y} {
    for {set i $x} {$i < $y} {incr i} {
        puts "x=$x y=$y i=$i"
        if {$i >= 7} {
            return -code break
        }
    }
}

for {set a 5} {$a < 10} {incr a} {
    set b [expr {$a + 5}]
    puts "a=$a b=$b"
    example $a $b
}
```

Then you'll see that you get this output:

```
a=5 b=10
x=5 y=10 i=5
x=5 y=10 i=6
x=5 y=10 i=7
```

If you use a straight `break` instead, you get this:

```
a=5 b=10
x=5 y=10 i=5
x=5 y=10 i=6
x=5 y=10 i=7
a=6 b=11
x=6 y=11 i=6
x=6 y=11 i=7
a=7 b=12
x=7 y=12 i=7
a=8 b=13
x=8 y=13 i=8
a=9 b=14
x=9 y=15 i=9
```

The straight `break` just terminates that innermost loop, the `return -code break` terminates the loop *in the caller*.

---

Did you know that you can implement the `break` command (inefficiently) using this:

```
proc break {} {
    return -code break
}
```